# How to convert integer to int in Gradle

Tags: gradle

It seems Gradle is wrapping int value with Integer object and hence I am getting the following error:

```
No signature of method: static org.gradle.plugins.javascript.envjs.http.simple.SimpleHttpFileServerFactory.start() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File, java.lang.Integer) values: [/Users/lex/Documents/github/proj/build/distributions, 8001]
```

I tried using a variable instead of 8001 directly but it also didn't work:

- def port = 8001
- int port = 8001

What is the correct way to pass an int value to the start method?

Answer (score 0):

the following code worked fine for me,

```
SimpleHttpFileServerFactory factory = new SimpleHttpFileServerFactory()
server = factory.start(new File("..dir..."), (int)port)
```